# Rails: Controller-specific menu in layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I add a controller-specific menu (or div) inside a general application layout in Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

method 1: set a variable in that controller

```
class SomeController
  before_filter :set_to_use_menu

  private

  def set_to_use_menu
    @use_menu = true
  end
end
```

method 2: determine the controller's name in the layout

```
<%- if controller_name == "your_controller_name" %>
  <%= render :partial => "the_menu" %>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of @use_menu, i.e. where is it used?

Comment: thanks I think I'll use a modified version of your first approach.

Comment: @michael: I believe PeterWong wants to use @use_menu in the layout to condition rendering of the menu html

Comment: Why would anyone considert the first approach when the second one is shorter and only requires you to add code only on the layout file?

Answer (score 4):

If I have correctly understood the question you needs to special place in layout.

Use <%= yield(:) %> in desired position in layout, for example:

```
    # application.html.erb
    <%= yield(:right_menu) %>

    # show.html.erb
    <% content_for :right_menu do %>
    <!-- Everything in this block will be shown at the position yield(:right_menu) in layout -->
    <% end %>
```

See more in 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Comment: thanks but this is controller-action-specific, not controller specific. I will have to add the content_for in every view rendered by the controller

Answer (score 1):

Other than the content_for approach (which may or may not be what you want), there are a few additional options.

You could use a before_filter in your controller to set a variable:

```
# Controller
class TestController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_variable

  def set_variable
    @my_variable = true
  end
end

# Layout
if @my_variable
  # Do the controller-specific stuff you want to do
end
```

Or, you could leave the controller alone and just check for the controller name in your layout:

```
# Layout
if controller.controller_name == 'test'
  # Do the controller-specific stuff you want to do
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call an appropriately named partial in your layout

```
<%= render :partial => "#{controller_name}_menu" %>
```

If your controller is `WidgetsController`, then this will use the partial `_widgets_menu.html.erb` under `./app/views/layouts`